# How to include a directory of a personal package?

Tags: pdftex

What do I need to do, to compile this:

Folder structure:

```
Main folder
|- main.tex
|- template/
   |- Preamble.sty
   |- ...
```

Content of main.tex:

```
...
\usepackage{Preamble}
...
```

When I compile with `pdflatex main.tex` it always says:

> LaTeX Error: File `Preamble.sty' not found.

When I upload the exact same code to Overleaf everything works fine :/

Comment: Put `Preamble.sty` in a directory where LaTeX can find it. The current (main) directory, if all else fails. You can also try using `\input{…}`

Comment: @Ingmar This does not work for my use case. If I do what you suggest then only Preamble will be added. But in Preamble there are many references to other files in the template folder. I cant possibly change every \usepackage and \input in the entire template folder.

Comment: Adding your `template` folder to the environment variable `TEXINPUTS` (temporarily) might work (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/4483042).